# Are there design patterns that make it easy convert an internal (backend) service to an external (RESTful) service?

Tags: rest, design-patterns, backend

In designing a platform infrastructure, I am creating several services that are
used internally.  These services might use binary protocol messages to exchange
information.  Down the line, I may want to expose these services externally, as
a RESTful service over http.

Are there design patterns or techniques that can ease this process of
converting an internal service to an external one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to organize the software into logical layers according to [Multilayered Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture). More specifically, [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) design pattern described by Martin Fowler captures the essence what you are trying to achieve.

This way you will have an inventory of internal services that are then used from the upper layers e.g. user interfaces, REST gateways, web services etc.

In the book [The Java EE Architect's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0972954880) Mr. Ashmore describes the same concept using the term deployment layer that sits on top of the service layer.